# Pyrogram - как по username чата получить его id

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyrogram

Пишу скрипт, требуется usernameы чатов преобразовать в id, docs pyrogram ничего нормального не выдают, а обработать надо 10000+ юзернеймов
Вот код:

```
while i != count:
    sleep(1)
    with Client(str(session), api_id, api_hash) as app:
        print(Fore.MAGENTA + f'\nЗапускаю сессию... ({session}/{count})\n')
        with open('links.txt', "r") as links:
            for link in links:
                try:
                    #На этой строчке username должен преобразовываться в id
                    app.send_message(chat_id, msg)
                except:
                    app.join_chat(f"{link}")
                    print(Fore.GREEN + f'Аккаунт присоединился по ссылке {link}')
                    sleep(10)
                except FloodWait as e:
                    print(Fore.RED + f'Аккаунт словил флуд, сплю {e.value} секунд')
                    sleep(e.value)
                    app.join_chat(f"{link}")
                    print(Fore.GREEN + f'Аккаунт присоединился по ссылке {link}')
                    sleep(10)
                except BadRequest as err:
                    print(Fore.RED + f'Неверная ссылка\n')
                except Exception as error:
                    print(Fore.RED + f"Unexpected ERROR: {error}\n")
        app.stop()
        session += 1
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chat = app.get_chat("Username")
chat_id = chat.id
```